# questions about why we receive answers from specifics systems with multiple gateways and others not

Tags: linux, networking, routing, gateway

I'm not sure how to title this question, so if you have any ideas just give them to me. I was planning to put it on serverfault but I've been redirected here by modos. This question couldn't be answered by many professionals of the sector so I hope to get an answer here. 
I'm troubling for several days now on my semi-pro network setup.
Here is a basic diagram of it: 
[image: simplified setup]

So I'm going to try to be very simple about this.
The server in question will be a ubuntu server VM. 
Router A,B and laptop can ping each other just fine but router A and laptop won't be able to ping the server on the address 192.168.5.31. It will possible through 192.168.3.4.
The problem stays with a gateway setup in the vm @192.168.3.1 or without any default gateway.

The problem doesn't appear with a NAS for example like QNAP or synology which will be available at the 2 addresses from anywhere in that network.

Of course the router A have a route describing how to reach 192.168.5.0/25, so every router knows how to reach every VLAN. Everything goes through the switch and reach or a host or a router, no vlan routing on the switch.

So is there any limitation to the principle of gateway ? Something like, if a packet is received on the secondary NIC from a IP outside of the subnet it is not answered?
And sorry if it lack of crucial informations or if I lack of ideas to precise the title or other things, I'm open to suggestion. I really didn't know how to ask and lack of imagination about keywords and didn't find anything in my CISCO training program about that.

Comment: It might be interesting to run tcpdump on the server to see if it ever gets the ping requests, and if it replies, and what the replies look like.

Comment: Are you saying the hypervisor is 192.168.3.4 and the guest VM is 192.168.5.31?  Did you configure the hypervisor to ip forward?  If the hypervisor is Linux, you can configure forwarding with https://serverfault.com/a/140626 --edit:  The iptables section describes port forwarding, but the cat proc sys and echo 1 proc sys sections are simple ip forwarding if you don't have restrictive IP tables rules.

Comment: no no, we are not discussing about the hypervisor here, we are discussing about the vm itself who has 2 NIC. And the iptables are not in question here since it is on accept policy. If you have a similar setup you can easily do the test too. I'm going to try tcpdump later this day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the IPs/netmasks you have, this is the expected result:

your laptop knows where to find `192.168.2.0-127`

your server knows where to find `192.168.3.0-127` and `192.168.5.0-127`

router A knows where to find `192.168.1.0-127` and `192.168.3.0-127`

router B knows where to find `192.168.2.0-127` and `192.168.5.0-127`

So from the above, the expected behavior is that the server's IP address `192.168.5.31` will be reachable only from router B. Moreover, for the whole thing to work the server must use router B's `192.168.5.1` as gateway for replies to all incoming traffic to `192.168.5.31`. Otherwise, with a default gateway of `192.168.3.1`, the server will receive a `ping` from the laptop (`192.168.2.30`) on `192.168.5.31` via router B, **but** will answer via  router A (`192.168.3.1`), if this is its default gateway, or will simply not answer with no default gateway. Laptop will ignore the packet, if the request was routed via router B and the server replies via router A. As a generic rule, the reply **must** follow the reverse path of the request.

[Policy routing](http://blog.scottlowe.org/2013/05/29/a-quick-introduction-to-linux-policy-routing/) will probably come in very handy in a setup like this. You will have to set up rules on the server so that when there is incoming traffic on `192.168.5.31` the replies go via router B and when there is incoming traffic on `192.168.3.4` the replies are routed via router A.

Comment: oooow okey so since it has used possibly another gateway then the receiver will ignore the packet?But you are talking about router here, so even in internal they are gonna filtered some packets? In your way of explaining I was more on the verge of thinking that the laptop will refuse the packet in response of a different path? And why then it is working with NAS? because it's a more complex system with several gateways or things like that?

Comment: Maybe I was a bit oblique. Server "knows" about ip ranges 192.168.3.0-127 and 192.168.5.0-127, and has a default gateway 192.168.3.1. Laptop (192.168.2.30) sends an ICMP packet to 192.168.5.31. The server does not know where to find 192.168.2.30, so it sends a response via the default gateway, from address 192.168.3.4. Laptop sees an ICMP response from a stranger, it ignores it.
I cannot say why it works with the NAS, unless I see its configuration.

Comment: Would the aforementioned NAS be a FreeBSD based product?

Comment: okey so it's more the laptopt that ignores it, It makes a lot more sense. Would I see it with tcpdump ? 
And for the NAS actually it is same result for QNAP and synology. So Now that you've enlightened me on the behaviour, I would guess that it has some sort of double gateways for "private ip's"

Comment: Yes, the packets should be visible with tcpdump, like in "tcpdump -i eth0 -n icmp and host 192.168.2.30". The NASes you mention are both based on FreeBSD, and from my experience with pfSense (FreeBSD also) it needs no extra configuration to reply via the correct interface and/or IP address. pf does its magic and everything works like a charm. This behavior can also be achieved with Linux, but you need to apply policy routing.

Comment: Great big big thanks @gmelis. It was clear and very constructive. It gives me a beter idea of what I was lacking.